# get attributes from attributes using gettattr

Tags: python, fastapi

Everytime i run my code it return me it returns an empty json
this is a block of code from my main file which should return a specified audio type with specified ID
i have tried to access attributes from attributes using two getattr here but it returns nothing

```
from new_project import models

class AudioType(str, Enum):
    Song = "Song"
    Podcast = "Podcast"
    Audiobook = "Audiobook"

@app.get('/{audio_type}/{audio_id}')
def show_one(audio_type: AudioType,audio_id: int, db: Session = Depends(database.get_db)):
    if audio_type == AudioType.Song:
        return db.query(getattr(getattr(models, audio_type), "id")).filter(audio_id == id)
```

thus is my models.py file

```
class Song(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'song'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String(100), nullable=False)
    duration = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    uploadTime = Column(DateTime(timezone=True))
    __table_args__ = (
        CheckConstraint(duration >= 0, name='check_bar_positive'),
        {})


class Podcast(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'podcast'
    id = Column(Integer, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(100), nullable=False)
    duration = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    uploadTime = Column(DateTime(timezone=True))
    host = Column(String(100), nullable=False, )
    #participants = Column
    __table_args__ = (
        CheckConstraint(duration >= 0, name='check_bar_positive'),
        {})

class Audiobook(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'audiobook'
    id = Column(Integer, unique=True, primary_key=True ,nullable=False)
    title = Column(String(100), nullable=False)
    author = Column(String(100), nullable=False, )
    narrator = Column(String(100), nullable=False)
    duration = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    uploadTime = Column(DateTime(timezone=True))
    __table_args__ = (
        CheckConstraint(duration >= 0, name='check_bar_positive'),
        {})
```

Comment: Why do you use `getattr`? `models.Song.id` is the same as `getattr(getattr(models, audio_type), "id")` in your case

Comment: Also `id` is a built-in function. Here `.filter(audio_id == id)` you don't have `id` defined, so you are comparing `audio_id` to a function which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych but then i will have to write models.Song.id for everytype, by using getattr the code will be shorter. (i guess)

Comment: Anyway, `.filter(audio_id == id)` should probably be `.filter(id=audio_id)`

Comment: As for `getattr`, if you can avoid it, avoid it. You are checking that it's `AudioType.Song` anyway, so it doesn't make sense in the code you have provided.

Comment: alright so i removed the if conditions, and .filter(id=audio_id) but it did not work.